# mapping resultset to json

Tags: java, json, resultset

I have some resultset data as follows :

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Code4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |    11 |   111 |  1111 |
|     2 |    21 |   211 |  2111 |
|     2 |    22 |   221 |  2211 |
|     2 |    21 |   212 |  2121 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I need the above result set to be converted to following two jsons.

```
code1_code2 = {
               1 : [11],
               2 : [21, 22, 21]
              };

code2_code3 = {
               11 : [111],
               21 : [211, 212],
               22 : [221]
              };
```

i have tried parsing the result set and as the 1st column is ordered i could get the 1st json.
But as the second column is not ordered i couldnot get the 2nd json.

(Note:- i would not be getting the 2nd column ordered)

Comment: Write a loop to get the values into a data structure(hashmap maybe) and convert it into json using some json lib(GSON maybe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**

The name in name/value pair of [JSON](https://www.json.org) should be string (not a number in your question).

[image: JSON Object]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/object.gif))</sub>

### Sample code

As mentioned in @josnidhin 's comment, you can use `Map` to store these data no matter if the result set is ordered or not.

Here's a sample code, I choose [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) to handle JSON stuff.

```
package test;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import net.sf.json.*;

public class StackOverflowQ10976771_ResultSetToJSON
{
    public static void appendValue (Map<String,  List<Integer>> map, String key, int value)
    {
        List<Integer> values = map.get (key);
        if (values == null)
        {
            values = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
            map.put (key, values);
        }
        values.add (value);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Map<String, List<Integer>> code1_code2 = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, List<Integer>> ();
        Map<String, List<Integer>> code2_code3 = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, List<Integer>> ();
        Map<String, List<Integer>> code3_code4 = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, List<Integer>> ();

        int[][] sample_resultSet = {
                {1, 11, 111, 1111},
                {2, 21, 211, 2111},
                {2, 22, 221, 2211},
                {2, 21, 212, 2121},
        };

        //ResultSet rs = null;
        //while (rs.next ())
        for (int[] rs : sample_resultSet)
        {
            appendValue (code1_code2, String.valueOf(rs[0]), rs[1]);
            appendValue (code2_code3, String.valueOf(rs[1]), rs[2]);
            appendValue (code3_code4, String.valueOf(rs[2]), rs[3]);
        }

        System.out.println ("code1_code2 =");
        System.out.println (JSONObject.fromObject (code1_code2).toString(4 ,4) + ";");
        System.out.println ();

        System.out.println ("code2_code3 = ");
        System.out.println (JSONObject.fromObject (code2_code3).toString(4 ,4) + ";");
        System.out.println ();

        //System.out.println ("code3_code4 = ");
        //System.out.println (JSONObject.fromObject (code3_code4).toString(4 ,4) + ";");
        //System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

### Sample output

```
code1_code2 =
    {
        "1": [11],
        "2":         [
            21,
            22,
            21
        ]
    };

code2_code3 = 
    {
        "11": [111],
        "21":         [
            211,
            212
        ],
        "22": [221]
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a tree structure first. Then each level of the tree, you output as JSON. This is basically a minute change of BFS (also called level order traversal).